# Somehow, 1 + 48 outputs 17, then 1

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a function in C where you input an integer as a parameter and the function will output using `putchar()` its binary value. So for example, on a 32-bit system, -1 as a parameter would print out char "1" (or int 49) thirty-two times (complement of 2).

My function does that... but somehow the last 4 ones that should've gotten printed out are not "1" (or int 49). But instead, I get int 17, then int 1 three times.

Here's the code:

```
int putbin(unsigned int b) {
  int zero = 48;
  int i = 0;
  if (b == 0) {
    putchar('0');
  } else {
    while (b != b % 2){
      // putchar(b & 1 + 48);
      printf("test %d:",i);
      printf("%d ",b & 1 + zero);
      printf("%d ",b);
      printf("%d ",b & 1);
      printf("%d ",zero);
      newline();
      b = b >> 1;
      i++;
    }
    printf("last one ");
    putchar(b + '0');
  }
}
```

I'm not supposed to use `printf()` at all, but for keeping an eye on variables I'm temporarily using it.

Calling the function:

```
putbin(-1)
```

Output this:

```
test 0:49 -1 1 48 
test 1:49 2147483647 1 48 
test 2:49 1073741823 1 48 
test 3:49 536870911 1 48 
test 4:49 268435455 1 48 
test 5:49 134217727 1 48 
test 6:49 67108863 1 48 
test 7:49 33554431 1 48 
test 8:49 16777215 1 48 
test 9:49 8388607 1 48 
test 10:49 4194303 1 48 
test 11:49 2097151 1 48 
test 12:49 1048575 1 48 
test 13:49 524287 1 48 
test 14:49 262143 1 48 
test 15:49 131071 1 48 
test 16:49 65535 1 48 
test 17:49 32767 1 48 
test 18:49 16383 1 48 
test 19:49 8191 1 48 
test 20:49 4095 1 48 
test 21:49 2047 1 48 
test 22:49 1023 1 48 
test 23:49 511 1 48 
test 24:49 255 1 48 
test 25:49 127 1 48 
test 26:49 63 1 48 
test 27:17 31 1 48 
test 28:1 15 1 48 
test 29:1 7 1 48 
test 30:1 3 1 48 
last one 1
```

The numeric value after each test is the integer I pass to the function `putchar()` in order to print out my ones. As you can see, at first it's correctly outputting 49, or "1" as expected. Then somehow it becomes 17 then 1, 1, 1, 1.

The numeric value after that is `b`, which is the integer value we want to print our ones or zeroes from, with each iteration, I right-shift all its bits.

The 3rd numeric value is `b & 1`. As expected, it outputs 1.

The 4th numeric value is variable `zero` that I defined as `int zero = 48`. I just thought it could've been the one who caused issue.

I'm quite lost at why 1 + 48 (`b & 1 + zero`) would give me 17 instead of 49.

Comment: `b & 1 + zero` is not the same as `(b & 1) + zero`. It is the same as `b & (1+zero)`

Comment: `int zero = 48` **nice**

Comment: Re: user3386109's correct answer (inexplicably as a comment; @user3386109, I recommend promotion to an answer), see https://www.swansontec.com/sopc.html for a summary of operator precedence in C. `+` is higher up than `&`. So, in the absence of brackets, `+` operations will occur **before** `&` operations. In much the same way that in ordinary maths `1 + 3 * 3` is `10`, not `12`, something like `4 & 1 + 3` is `4`, not `3`.

Comment: sorry, I cannot not come back to that `int zero = 48`: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V4CggHUypjY

Comment: please, please `int zero ='0';` or even better `char zero = '0';` or even better since its less typing just use '0' in place of `zero`

Comment: @pm100 not to mention that C doesn't guarantee ASCII, so '0' could be something other than 48. Though then we'd have to get into not making assumptions about `'1' - '0'` that are very academic in practice.

Comment: @Tommy = my first c prog ran on an EBCDIC machine , so not that academic. It also had null == 0xffffffff

Comment: @pm100 EBCDIC is the only non-ASCII I looked up, but it also has '0' adjacent to '1' so you'd get away with the same logic there. I found that IBM 48-character BCDIC from 1934 doesn't obey the same logic, as it puts '0' after '9' instead of before '1', but they appear to have decided that encoding was a misfeature at least as early as 1954.

Comment: @Tommy  C specifies `'0'`, `'1'`, .... `'9'` are sequential regardless of the character set.  `b + '0'` is fine and probable.

Comment: @truvaking Note: `putbin(unsigned int b)` alternative: `void putbin(unsigned int b) { if (b > 1) putbin(b/2); putchar(b%2 + '0');}`

Comment: i would probably never do int zero = 48 or int zero = '0', but i just thought it couldve been possible that it somehow changed its value and wanted to keep an eye on it using printf().

Answer (score 6):

In C, `b & 1 + zero` is equivalent to `b & (1 + zero)` since `+` has a higher [precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) than `&`.

You need to surround `b & 1` in parentheses to ensure that it gets calculated before `zero` is added:

```
printf("%d ",(b & 1) + zero);
```

Answer (score 1):

the following proposed code:

1. does not output all the extra data
2. performs the desired functionality of breaking a unsigned `int` into a series of 0s and 1s
3. uses the value 21 for a test sample
4. assumes a `int` is 32 bits wide

and now the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// prototypes
void putbin(unsigned int b);

int main( void )
{
    putbin( 21 );
}


void putbin(unsigned int b)
{
    for( int i=31; i >= 0; i-- )
    {
        if( b & ( (unsigned)1 << (unsigned)i ) )
        {
            putchar( '1' );
        }

        else
        {
            putchar( '0' );
        }
    }
}
```

The output from the above code is:

```
00000000000000000000000000010101
```